# Rebuild search index inside Sitecore 10.1 CMS not showing sitecore_web_index or sitecore_master_index or sitecore_web_core

Tags: solr, content-search

I was trying to implement search functionality with Solr on Sitecore 10.1 instance. But I am not able to find the following default indexes:

- `sitecore_web_index`
- `sitecore_master_index`
- `sitecore_web_core`

[image]

Some notes:
i. Solr is up and running smoothly
ii. All Solr config files inside app_config are enabled, (Examples folder, ContentSearch folder)

A snapshot of Solr cores:
[image]

Are there any settings I'm missing? Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks community for your immense help, I'm looking forward to a solution.

**Update:**
The above issue was caused by adding all the Solr config files which were present inside `<instance>\App_Config\Include\Examples` folder, which had these files:

- `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild.config`
- `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.SwitchOnRebuild.config`

The above files overrode Solr default config files and switched to Solr cloud.
Thanks to @Cristy for his help. Disabling the Solr cloud configs fixed the issue.

Hope this helps anyone who is facing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Cristi for your help again, yes I have that file inside ContentSearch folder, which also includes Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config

Comment: Can you verify in /sitecore/admin/Showconfig.aspx what configration you have for sitecore_master_index? And if you deployed all schemas to solr, I can see from printscreen that you have lindesc_?

Comment: Try repopulating indexes and then restart solr

Comment: @CristiVulturar While inspecting Showconfig.aspx, Im able to find sitecore_master_index inside patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild.config".

Comment: @Mahesh Just did, didnt change anything!

Comment: Check logs. And post the whole core, master and web index config sections from showconfig in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the file `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config` is present in the \App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch\ folder. When verifying with /sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx page you should be seeing the definition of `<index id="sitecore_master_index"` in the configuration.

If you take a look at the definition of the indexes they all have `<sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement" search:require="solr">`, could you verify in web.config if you have `<add key="search:define" value="Solr"/>` set and `<add key="role:define" value="Standalone"/>`?

I am not sure why you have `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild.config` enabled, by default this file is disabled. If you take a look in it there are some <patch:delete /> for the sitecore_master index. If you don't have solrcloud you should comment out this file or try to use `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.SwitchOnRebuild.config` instead.

Comment: Thanks Cristi, I have checked, `<add key="role:define" value="Standalone"/>` and `<add key="search:define" value="Solr"/>` are present in the web.config file

Comment: I updated the answer, please take a look at why you have Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud config enabled.

Comment: Ah Thanks a lot @Cristi. You are like god of Sitecore to me ^_^



It worked, I just disabled the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrCloud.SwitchOnRebuild.config` file, which I accidentally enabled following a Sitecore blog on the net.


Thanks a lot for the help! Kudos!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, but my solution was a little different so adding it here for future reference.

It turned out that these 3 files:

> ```
> Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config
> Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config
> Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config
> ```

Found under "~\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch" were getting overwritten by the custom solution ones of my project, and the
`<param desc="core">INSERTCOREINDEXNAME</param>` field inside them looked like `<param desc="core">{id}</param>` rather than have the correct core name inside it

Once I fixed the 3 params to include the correct core names they showed up in my instance's index manager.